# Usage of "compensate" as a recompense for gain instead of loss

Tags: verbs

To keep this PG, I've changed the popular saying we've all heard:

> *"He has a huge truck to compensate for his small **ego**"*

But I've recently been using a sort of counter to the joke, in one form or another (which will need some translation to be funny, or funnier I guess):

> *"I have a small truck to compensate for my large **ego**"*

My question is, is this a correct usage of the word **compensate**?  Can you compensate for something large with something smaller?

Comment: Did you look it up in a dictionary?

Comment: @drɱ65δ, yes but all the definitions were in some form of "Recompense for **loss**", not "Recompense for an improper balance"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/compensate) can answer your question:

> **2.** to counterbalance; offset; be equivalent to: *He compensated his homely appearance with great personal charm.*

Imagine scales balancing your large ego on the one side with the small truck on the other.

Comment: Woohoo!  The joke lives on